# Define a distance metric in R

Tags: r

It is my first time on the forum, so please excuse any unusual formatting...

I am currently working on clustering algorithms for mixed data types and am using the k-prototype approach implemented in the clustMixType package. This works perfectly fine. 
However, I would like now to derive some validity measures for this clustering approach. The packages available in R either require numeric input data or a distance matrix. I am therefore trying to derive this distance matrix using the equation given in Huang 1998: 
d(X,Y) = sum(xj-yj)^2 + γ*sum(δ(xj,yj))
I tried the following:

```
mat.f <- data.frame(runif(5),runif(5),factor(c("men","women","women","women","men"),levels = c("men","women")))
mat.m <- as.matrix(mat.f)
myfunction <- function(x,y){
    try(sum((x-y)^2))+lambda*try(sum(x!=y))
}
proxy::dist(mat.m,myfunction)
```

And get as an output:

```
1  2  3  4
2 NA         
3 NA NA      
4 NA NA NA   
5 NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
In do.call(".External", c(list(CFUN, x, y, pairwise, if (!is.function(method)) get(method) else method),  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

which is obviously not what I am looking for. 
My question is therefore: 
How can I tell R that he should, depending on the type of the data, do one of the distance computations?
I might also understand something wrong in the definition of Huang 1998.

It would be great if you could help me solve this issue.

If I need to give any more details, please ask.

Thank you already for your help!

Comment: `mat.m` is a character matrix. `x-y` is not defined for characters.

Comment: `proxy::dist` accepts a data.frame as input. You could coerce the factor to integer. Then you'd have all numeric input.

Comment: Thank you Roland for your answer. However I am not sure it is what I want. I would like to keep the factors as character data (or factors) and define a metric that can differentiate whether the input is character or numeric and compute the total distance accordingly... I hope this makes my question clearer.